# Finding/setting css line-height defaults

Tags: cross-browser, user-agent, css

One strange thing I've noticed when trying to normalize my css across browsers is that default line-height properties for h-elements and other major tag types are different across browsers like Chrome and Firefox, and yet are not set at the user-agent level:

- http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css
- http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css

Moreover, popular normalizers like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) don't take care of that either.

So my question is two parts:

1. If line-heights aren't set at the user agent level, where are the default values coming from?
2. I'd rather not normalize line-heights myself, but if I have to, where is a good example of some defaults?

Comment: See [here](http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/) and [here](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/).

Comment: @Yarin - jokes apart - I don't really get what you need? The default line-height is what you as designer decide for your page design. And you should set that on top of your css. The browser default is what you posted in the links (html.css) and that is where it comes from.

Comment: @easwee- As my question states, line-height css values aren't set in the default browser css, so I'm trying to understand where the cross-browser disparity is coming from. With respect, if you've never dealt with normalizing css before then you don't need to be handling this question.

Comment: @Yarin - line-height IS set by the user-agent since it is calculated on the base of the largest font used in a certain element. But yeah - I can't tell you which browser script calculates this - it's a browser thing and I never cared about normalizing css. I find that overdoing it and clients usually don't pay for that.

Comment: it's like asking, do we need to eliminate disease from the world. And the answer given would be "No" as long as you have the medicine for it. Do web sites need to be experienced exactly the same in every browser. Yes! But since it is not possible due to too many varibales, OS, Screen Resolutions, Browser Versions, Rendering engines, to name a few, the excuse given is "No".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I agree that "things aren't meant to be exactly the same" is somewhat of a cop-out, especially as even IE comes on board with pretty good standards adoption.

Relative (120%, 1, 1em) line-height values are based on the computed font-size, Normal is supposed to be based on font size but it can and does vary from browser to browser, as you can see by opening up this example in FF and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mahalie/BSMZe/6/

I generally look to [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/css/main.css) for queues on best practices since it is so popular (and therefore well vetted / under a lot of scrutiny. They use:

```
body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }
```

And their discussion of it is quite interesting although no perspective is the clear winner: 
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/724

Comment: @mahalie- Thanks for stepping up and giving a real answer! Great links.  +2

Comment: Link should now be https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css

Comment: This is outdated as they're clearly using a different (and more accessible) approach right now by letting the browser use it's default values.

Comment: HTML5 Boilerplate now uses `line-height: 1.4;`. You can see it on [this line in the CSS](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css#L23).

Comment: Can't believe people are still using this thread, thank you @Teepeemm for updating my answer :D Happy baselining all...