# Layout broken in IE 10. Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome are working fine

Tags: css, cross-browser, compatibility

http://www.alecos.it/new/125027/125027.php this link is an example of my problem... I used a png 1x16 for drawing the rows... the rows are visible in the link posted... my question is:

why under IE 6/8, FireFox, Opera, Safari and other browsers the rows are perfectly aligned with the text while under IE 9/10/11 the text do not fit in the rows?

I used a simple css:

```
/* Style Source Code */
.code {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: #6666FF 1px solid;
  background-color: #FFF5EE;
  background-image: url("../bkg/Bkg_116.png");  /* Horizontal Rows */
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 10px;
}
/* Style Source Code */
.xcode {
  color: #008000;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, FreeMono, 'Nimbus Mono L', monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}

/* Style Div */
.alignment {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Hope in workround to fix the issue...

here there is my css: http://www.alecos.it/css/alecos.css

Comment: adjust line-height: 16px; in the .xcode class 

check this [Finding/setting css line-height defaults][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849506/finding-setting-css-line-height-defaults

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on Windows machine right now but my guess is `.xcode(line-height:16px;}` would solve your problem, but I must say that this is the wrong way of creating row borders. Why not add:

```
.xcode td{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;}
```

instead of using background image?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is temporarily outdated unti it's next update meaning that it's browser does not have the ability to process codes in the same manner as other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

.alignment    `{line-height: 20px;}`
Gets over ruled by `.xcode line-height normal;`

IE aint normal ;)

Besides content tages like h1, p, font all have slightly different margins/paddings around them. So a non responsive img isnt the best way to go.

Would be better if you could wrap each line with a span, div or sinces its a table a tr,td and give those a border-bottom.

Gr.
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your text inside `.xcode` aligned with the horizontal lines, the "code" lines must be distributed vertically. Unfortunately, It seems that you did not understand the meaning of `line-height` property and use the default value without considerations.

## The line-height property

[image]

As you can see, the `line-height` property will decide how much is the distance of two lines of text. In your case, we need it to be exactly `16px` inside the whole block of `.xcode`.

## The value of `normal` value of the `line-height` property

From the [W3C CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), the value of `normal` value is defined as:

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2.

From some online resource like [this article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/) or [this page](http://css-class.com/test/css/text/linebox-line-height-011.html), you can see that the real value of `normal` value depends on many arguments like font size, font family, OS, user agent, ... Therefore, it is recommended that you should use some *css normalize stylesheet* to set the value of `line-height` correctly and cross-browser.

## About your case

The quick fix here is setting the `line-height` inside the `.xcode` class to be `16px` (which is the height of the of your background image).

Comment: .xcode {line-height: 16px; } solved my problem... I forgot that I had declarated in .xcode line-height: normal; It's a stupid mistake... I know as to use line-height only I forgot that the value was declarated in .xcode class as normal, changed in 16px worked fine. Thanks very much!