# What is the CSS height of a line of text? It doesn’t seem to be 1em

Tags: css, height, font-size

Look at this fiddle:

```js
function toggle(event) {
    var element = document.getElementById('changeme');
    element.innerText = element.innerText ? '' : 'some text';
}
button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = toggle;
```

```css
#changeme {
    min-height: 1em;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id=button type=button value='Toggle content'>
<p id=changeme>dynamically changing content
<p>This should not move (up and down)
```

I have a text element there (it is a `<p>`, but could be a `<div>`) which I sometimes set to be empty. (Use the button to toggle between empty and some content.)

What height does this element with a line of text have? I want a generic answer so I can set its `min-height` to that value so that the element doesn’t collapse when empty. I thought `1em` is what I’m looking for, but `1em` seems to be the size of letters like “W” without the space below the baseline for letters like “g”.

I’m looking for a neat trick to give the possibly empty element a constant height, without putting `&nbsp;` into it. (At the moment I use `1.5em`.)

Comment: The default value of `line-height` is `1.2` / `1.2em` or `120%` in most of web browsers.

Comment: as @HashemQolami said : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4g9wnptp/19/

Comment: related questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849506/finding-setting-css-line-height-defaults  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163788/line-height-default-value-if-font-size-is-100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact calculation of heights of lines is complicated (see CSS 2.1 section 10 [Visual formatting model details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html)), but in a simple case like this, the height is determined by the `line-height` value when the element is not empty. When it is empty, the height would be empty, but the `min-height` setting forces the height to the font size (`1em`).

The initial value of [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) is browser-dependent, and it is expected to depend on the font, too. The default is in practice always larger than the font size. This explains what happens here.

To keep the height constant, it is best to explicitly set its `line-height` and to set `min-height` to the same value, e.g.

```
#changeme {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    min-height: 1.25em;
}
```

Note: The `em` unit means the size of the font, which is by definition the height of the font. This is a reference quantity and does not normally correspond to the height (or width) of any letter; the height of most letters is smaller than the font size (though this varies by letter and by font).

Comment: Look what I also found in section 10.6.1 of CSS 2.1: “Note: level 3 of CSS will probably include a property to select which measure of the font is used for the content height.” ...

Answer (score 1):

The default `line-height` is `normal` (valid CSS value for that property). You can’t set `min-height` to that value unfortunately.

Apart from `normal`, `line-height` can have fixed length values (which are of no interest here) or factors which work relative to the `font-size`. The numeric equivalent of `normal` is not just browser dependent, interestingly. It commonly ranges between 1.0 and 1.5 (without unit) for different font faces *and* font-sizes!

So set the `min-height` to something beautiful between 1em and 1.5em. Then set `line-height` to the same value to make sure it is actually the same.

Note that for `line-height` a value with em-unit or unit less mean the same: the former is a fixed length relative to the current font-size and the latter is a factor relative ... to the font-size.